# Vhost with Mamp Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: macos, mamp, vhosts

I'm having problem creating vhosts on my MacBook.

This is what I've done so far:

Added this to the Mamp vhost file

[image]

And added this to my host file

[image]

But when I try to access the link: localhost or mylearninglar.dev it does not work.

What am I doing wrong? I have done the same way on Windows and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need restart Mamp. 
By browsing to the domain that you configured your project will show